# Sugestão recomendações de uso para Wiki de tag rejeitada, como posso melhorar minhas futuras edições?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas, wikis-de-tags, qualidade

Sugeri uma **edição de recomendações de uso** e Wiki de tag, geralmente dou uma olhadinha no SOen, pois já pode existir uma, nesse caso, como já existia, decidi importá-la para o SOpt, tag [openlayers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers). Nesse caso, fiz a tradução e sugeri.

- A *wiki de tag* foi aprovada.
- As *recomendações de uso* foram rejeitadas.

Motivo apresentado:

> Simplesmente definir o que é uma [tag] raramente ajuda aqueles que a
>   usam a não ser que o próprio nome da tag seja ambíguo. Resumos devem
>   descrever por que e quando a tag deve ser utilizada. Visite a central
>   de ajuda para mais orientações.

Sugerida, [**rejeitada**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/69693):

> OpenLayers 2.x E uma biblioteca Javascript de Mapeamento web open
>   source Para uma Criação de Aplicações de Mapas na web. Não e
>   Compatível com o Mais recente OpenLayers 3.x (Veja a tag
>   openlayers-3).

Usada no SOen ([openlayers info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/openlayers/info)):

OpenLayers 2.x is an open source Javascript web mapping library for creating web map applications. It is not compatible with the newer OpenLayers 3.x (see openlayers-3 tag).

Nova sugestão [**aprovada**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/69692):

> OpenLayers é uma biblioteca Javascript de mapeamento web open source
>   para a criação de aplicações de mapas na web.

ou seja...

- **Como eu poderia proceder diante de uma futura situação semelhante, em que não há informações numa tag no SOpt, mas há no SOen?**
- **Por que uma sugestão/edição correta não foi feita por quem as rejeitou?** (Nesse caso, a pergunta também pode ser generalizada para
  todos)

Comment: Compare as duas sugestões que você fez, a segunda ficou muito superior e bem mais objetiva. Por isso eu rejeitei a primeira, e aprovei a segunda. No fragmento não pode ter muita "enrolação", já que é a informação que vai aparecer quando a pessoa selecionar ou passar o mouse na tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ninguém é obrigado a melhorar a edição, se a pessoa não se sente confortável realmente é melhor não mexer.

A nova edição ficou muito boa. Minha principal sugestão é copiar o que tem no SOen mesmo :) tente ver se pode melhorar algo para o uso no nosso contexto, mas são raras as *tags* onde isto fará sentido. Eventualmente algum lugar onde tem documentação em português seria legal. Mas não é obrigatório.

Colocar tudo capitalizado e erros ortográficos podem ter pesado na decisão de rejeitar.

Comment: Percebi os textos capitalizados em quanto criava está pergunta, eu realmente teria rejeitado a minha própria pergunta só por causa disso, por isso acho bom que mais alguém possa avaliar as edições.

Comment: @Florida então pode colocar esta resposta como certa para encerrar o assunto.